# Distinguish link opened in current tab vs. new tab

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Example of what I want to do: On Facebook, clicking a link to open it in the current tab will trigger some JavaScript rather than opening the link.  However, opening it in a new tab (either by right-clicking or by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>) will open the link without calling any JavaScript.

I'd like to do the same with my links (have link behaviour dependent on the target).  I have the `onclick` event handler `return false;` to avoid opening the link; but this causes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking to fail to open the link.  How do I achieve this?

EDIT: I **do not want** links to forcefully open in new windows.  **IF** a link is opened in a new window, I want it to follow the `href` as usual.  However, **IF** the link is opened in the current window, *rather than following the link in the current window*, I want to have some JavaScript run.

Facebook does this to open an image in a popup "theatre" if you open it in the current window, and open it in a full page if you open it in a new window.

Note that capturing the `click` event on links and using `preventDefault()` or `return false` causes <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click (open in new tab) to fail.  In any case, this should work regardless of how the link is opened - click, <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, etc.

EDIT 2: It seems that `hashchange` / HTML5 pushState is the correct way to go about this

Comment: Do you want the link to always open in new window?

Comment: cant you just change the target to `_blank` on all the anchors?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `href` of the anchor pointing to correct url. This way right click and open in a new tab or window will work fine.

Use jQuery to bind the `click` event handler to the anchor like this.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   //Do whatever javascript operation you want.
   if(!e.ctrlKey){
         e.preventDefault();//Stop the page to navigate to the url set in href
   }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/ekxZy/)**

Comment: Please don't confuse *links* (which are `A` elements with an `href` attribute) that are a source for navigation, with *anchors* (which are `A` elements with a `name` attribute) that are destinations. `A` elements can be both a *link* and an *anchor* at the same time, but it's not common.

Comment: It depends on the requirement but yes we should let link behave as a link.

Comment: Cmd+Click fails to open the link when I do this